# SQLQuery - Counting Values For A Range Across 2 Values Grouped-By 3rd Value in A Single Table

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by

I have a MySQL database structured as follows: (the numbers on the left are row numbers)

```
 +------------+----------+--------------+-------------+
 | start_dsgn | end_dsgn | min_cost_1   | min_cost_2  |
 +------------+----------+--------------+-------------+
1|          1 |        2 |            3 |         100 |
2|          1 |        3 |            5 |         153 |
3|          1 |        4 |           10 |         230 |
4|          2 |        1 |            4 |          68 |
5|          2 |        3 |            5 |         134 |
6|          3 |        1 |            7 |          78 |
7|          3 |        2 |            8 |         120 |
+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+
```

I would like to query the database such that for each start design, return the count of end designs for which one of the two cost inputs is less than the input.  So for example a user inputs a value for cost_1 and cost_2.  The query will return the count of the number of rows, grouped by design, in which cost_1  >= min_cost_1 OR cost_2 >= min_cost_2.

So for the database above lets assume the user inputs

```
cost_1 = 5
cost_2 = 100
```

This should return something like:

```
{1:2, 2:2, 3:1}
```

where the structure is:

```
{start_design_1: count(row 1 + row 2), start_design_2:count(row 4 + row 5) , start_design_3:count(row 6)}
```

I was just wondering if anyone had any tips or solutions on how to do this query as I am relatively new to SQL.  Thank you very much.

Also note that my database is not sorted as in the example, I did so to make the example easier to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify what version of SQL you are using so I am doing this example in SQL Server where @cost_1 is a variable. You can adapt it to the syntax for whatever SQL variant you are using. The following will give you the counts you want as a SQL result set:

```
SELECT start_dsgn, COUNT(CASE WHEN min_cost_1 <= @cost_1 OR min_cost_2 <= @cost_2 THEN end_dsng END) as Cnt
FROM table
GROUP BY start_dsgn
```

Once you have that, it's up to you to convert that into whatever format you want in whichever language you are using to query the database. You also didn't specify what language you are using, but it looks like you want a dictionary where start_dsgn is the key.

Most languages would return a list or array of either lists, tuples or dictionaries depending on what you use. From there it's pretty easy to convert them into any other form, at least in Python. Strongly typed languages like C#, Java and Swift are a little trickier.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `GROUP BY` to combine the rows for each value of `start_dsgn` thus:

```
select start_dsgn, count(*)
from Table1
group by start_dsgn
```

Add the criteria for cost in a `WHERE` clause. How to get them into the statement depends upon the language you are using - you will have to do some research. In Java it could be:

```
select start_dsgn, count(*)
from Table1
where where min_cost_1 <= ? or min_cost_2 <= ? 
group by start_dsgn
```

This will return it as a rowset - from your question you may have to convert this into a JSON structure. That isn't strictly an SQL thing so again you will have to research.

Fiddle is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/087c5/2

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving the query which was:

```
SELECT start_dsgn, count(*) FROM table_name WHERE cost_1 >= min_cost_1 OR cost_2 >= min_cost_2 GROUP BY start_dsgn;
```